# cannot open links with google-chrome

Tags: google-chrome

For example, there is a link http://www.google.com in terminal, usually I could right click on the link, select `open link` to open the link in google-chrome.

But now I cannot do this on ubuntu 15.10. Google-chrome only opens a blank page for me every time. It works in Firefox or Opera if I set the default browser as them, and it works on Windows, too. It just doesn't work on ubuntu 15.10 with google-chrome. I don't know if this is a bug of google-chrome or ubuntu. Has anyone encountered the same problem? How to fix it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/701775/165945 has the answer you're looking for.