# Slack fails to open links in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

Any time I try to open a link from Slack, all I get is a blank new window opening in Chrome. Worth reinstalling, or do others have this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm on fresh Ubuntu/Chrome/Slack and links were opening blank tabs in Chrome. [This AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/701775/578789) worked for me:

> Open file: `$HOME/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`
>
> Find the line:
>
> ```
> Exec=/opt/google/chrome/chrome
> ```
>
> Add a space and `%U`:
>
> ```
> Exec=/opt/google/chrome/chrome %U
> ```
>
> Then save the file.

Comment: Particularly, forgetting the argument is an easy mistake to make when creating your own desktop files, so this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: its work for me! find file sudo find -name 'google-chrome.desktop'      and edit nano ./.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

This was actually a problem with Google Chrome itself. Updated version fixed it.

Comment: Can you tell me which Chrome version you're running, that links work in? I'm having this same issue with 16.10

Comment: I don't remember which one it was -- I'm using `Google Chrome 55.0.2883.87` now and it's been fine.

Comment: Thanks. I did end up getting it working, and you reminded me to update this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get into the slack I just run `slack` command in commandline with the magic link as argument.

`slack slack://ABCDSF4MR/magic-login/892109304726-LONG_SECRETKEY`